# why is my Unity photon Pun2 import not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm trying to import unity Pun2 free assets but when i try to access any of the method i get an error. also all the imported scripts are showing errors. i have checked supported unity version for pun2. it says 2017.4.7+ and i'm using 2019.4.11f
Please someone help me i'm stuck here from last 2 days

[image]

Comment: What are these errors you get? Please add them to your question as **text**

Comment: photon methods are not recognized in script and also when i change MonoBehaviour to MoboBehaviorPunCallbacks i get "The type or namespace name 'MonoBehaviourPunCallBacks' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting that error only in vscode or in Unity as well?

I had a similar error where VSCode could not find anything related with Photon. In order to solve it, I installed the latest version of mono and then set in VSCode preferences "omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always.

Comment: sorry but i am new to VS. can you please tell me how to install latest version of mono?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. i installed unity 2019.4.17 and now it's working. thank you for your help guys.